# Что будет со слабой ссылкой в двойном замыкании?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть код:

```
func someFunc() {
    networkLayer.getSome { [weak self] result in
        guard let self else { return } 
        self.networkLayer.getOtherSome(from: result) { response in
            self.parse(response) // будет ли здесь сильный захват ссылки на self?
        }
    }
}
```

По сути, здесь сделан unwrap ссылки, потом это раскрытую ссылку захватываем в следующем замыкании. Но не понятно - какую ссылку захватываем во втором замыкании сильную или слабую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будет сильный захват.

Для слабого захвата нужно либо снова использовать `[weak self]`, либо убрать guard-присваивание (которое на самом деле и не нужно, если вся функция состоит из одного вызова).

Comment: функция состоит из одного вызова - это как пример. Но почему будет сильный захват? потому что weak это на самом деле просто как enum Optional?

Comment: Нет, к enum это отношения не имеет. Сильный захват будет, потому что после guard self переменная self уже указывает на сильную ссылку на self, а не на слабую. Дальше захват будет работать так же, как и с любой другой сильной ссылкой (то бишь, её нужно явно слабо захватывать через [weak self]). Для ещё более наглядной иллюстрации можно сделать guard wself = self и убедиться в том, что wself стала сильной ссылкой на self, а self осталась слабой.

Comment: спасибо большое за разьяснения!